# 2sxc send e-mail with the pdf file generated in the app-tutorial-pdf

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I need to improve the pdf demo app to send the pdf as an attachment.

The app-tutorial-pdf generates the file with:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class PdfController : Custom.Hybrid.Api14
{
  public static string generatorUrlPrefix = "/pdf/generator";

  [HttpGet]
  public async Task<dynamic> Document(int episode)
  {
    var cultureCode = CmsContext.Culture.CurrentCode.Substring(0, 2);

    var pdfService = CreateInstance("../Services/PdfService.cs");
    var printUrl = pdfService.AddPrintToken(CmsContext.Site.Url + generatorUrlPrefix + "/document?" + "episode=" + episode);

    byte[] pdfStream = await pdfService.GetWebPageAsPdf(printUrl);

    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + episode + ".pdf");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(pdfStream);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

    return pdfStream;
  }
}
```

Let's say I need to pick that file and use DNN Mail.SendMail feature to send it. How can this be achieved?

```
string xmailFrom = "something@test.me";
string xmailTo = "something@test.me";
string xcc = "";
string xbcc = "";
string xreplyTo = "";
string xsubject = "TestSubject";
string xbody = "TestBody";
string[] xattachments = [I need to place the pdfStream result here];
string xsmtpServer = "";
string xsmtpAuthentication = "";
string xsmtpUsername = "";
string xsmtpPassword = "";


Mail.SendMail(xmailFrom, xmailTo, xcc, xbcc, xreplyTo, MailPriority.Normal, xsubject, MailFormat.Html, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, xbody, xattachments, xsmtpServer, xsmtpAuthentication, xsmtpUsername, xsmtpPassword, DotNetNuke.Entities.Host.Host.EnableSMTPSSL);
```

Storing the pdf in the server would also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will need some experimentation, but the gist is this:

```
byte[] pdfStream = await pdfService.GetWebPageAsPdf(printUrl);
```

this puts all the bytes into `pdfStream`. You should now either save it to file, or convert this into the format needed by the `Mail.SendMail(...)` (not sure what this is).

To save it, google something like `c# save byte array to file` and you should be good to go.

To convert it to the format your Mail.SendMail uses, you'll have check what that API expects.